# Apache rewrite: How can I apply a rewrite to the result of a prior rewrite modification

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, blogs

I want to do a rewrite to reformat a dynamic (blog) URL to a php script to server the blog. I have the following working:

```
RewriteRule ^news-and-blog/(.+)$ /news-and-blog/php/serveblog.php?val=$1 [N]
```

Before setting this up, I have the existing in my .htaccess to ensure that any URL variants get redirected to https://www.example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
### START WWW & HTTPS

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Both the 'blog redirect' and the 'guarantee https://www' snippets seem to work fine independently but they clash when I combine them. I have tested both blocks with a .htaccess tester (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

**I want both to be applied: note i have put the [N] flag on the 'blog' redirect as [Apache manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) says**

> The [N] flag causes the ruleset to start over again from the top,
>   using the result of the ruleset so far as a starting point

I'd really appreciate any pointers on how I might be able to get the result that I wat whereby (1) any URI is forced to start https://www and (2) https://www.example.com/news-and-blog/test.html is redirected to .../news-and-blog/php/serveblog.php?val=test.html

Many thanks all